# Xcode keeps giving .signUp is only available in iOS 13.2 . Is this some Xcode bug?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sign-in-with-apple

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and trying to implement "Sign in with Apple". But Xcode keeps giving this error. I've tried rebuilding, clean building my project but nothing seems to work.

What I want to do is - if a device has iOS 13.2 show the "sign up with apple" else show the "sign in with apple" button since type:signup is available in iOS 13.2 or newer.
here's my code :

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
lazy var appleSignInButton:ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton = {
    let button : ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton
    if #available(iOS 13.2, *){
        button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signUp, style: .black)
    }else{
        button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style:.black)
    }
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appleSignUP), for: .touchDown)
    return button
}()
```

[image: This is the error message]

Comment: What is the `signUp` function?

Comment: I tried your code in playground and it's not giving any errors.

Comment: @George_E the signUp function creates an ASAuthorizationController with authorization request and performs the requests.
I've used @available(iOS 13.0,*) for that function and it's fine since another view controller has a similar function for login and works fine there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function instead of a computed property to work around this issue.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func getAppleSignInButton() -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
    let button: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton
    if #available(iOS 13.2, *) {
        button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signUp, style: .black)
    }else{
        button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)
    }
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appleSignUP), for: .touchDown)
    return button
}
```

You could also separate it out and keep the lazy var if you wanted.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
lazy var appleSignInButton: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton = {
    let button = getSignUpOrInButton()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appleSignUP), for: .touchDown)
    return button
}()

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func getSignUpOrInButton() -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
    if #available(iOS 13.2, *) {
        return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signUp, style: .black)
    } else {
        return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working. Although I don't understand why it's working now and why it showed an error in the first place.

Comment: I would assume that with the lazy var's original initialization being self-contained, it simply had stricter availability requirements. But to be honest, I'm not sure either. It took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.ButtonType.signUp
```

is indeed only available in iOS 13.2+, according to Apple's documentation:

```
SDKs

iOS 13.2+
macOS 10.15.1+
Mac Catalyst 13.2+
tvOS 13.1+
```

[ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton signUp Enumeration Case](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidbutton/buttontype/signup)